# Image file is not displayed, but url location is fetched correctly, also i get a type error in command line

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
import json
import os.path
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='h432hi5ohi3h5i5hi3o2hi'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        urls={}
        if os.path.exists('urls.json'):
            with open('urls.json') as urls_file:
                urls= json.load(urls_file)

        if request.form['shortname'] in urls.keys():
            flash('hey the short name is already there, so you could try another..')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

        f=request.files['file']  
        fullname=request.form['shortname'] + secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save('C:/Users/Desktop/PythonFlaskNick/static/user_files/ ' + fullname)
        urls[request.form['shortname']]={'file':fullname}    

        with open('urls.json','w') as urls_file:
            json.dump(urls,urls_file)
        return render_template('new.html',shortname=request.form['shortname'])
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/<string:code>')
def redirect_to_url(code):
    if os.path.exists('urls.json'):
        with open('urls.json') as urls_file:
            urls = json.load(urls_file)
            if code in urls.keys():
                return redirect(url_for('static', filename='user_files/' + urls[code]['file']))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I create a html form: `home.html` with 2 fields: `file` and `shortname` and another form:`new.html`,that simply returns the successful upload of file. Afer uploading the input is push into `urls.json` file, now am entering `localhost:5000/go` (where `go` is shortname for an image file stored in dictionary) it fetches the location correctly but returns 404 error and `image file is not displayed`, though i have it in my `urls.json` file. Kindly rectify this problem. And a message in cmd `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct, you are just missing a piece. The `/<string:code>` route redirects to the `static` route if the file is present in the json file but you didn't add it. The static route usually serves static files and most likely should look something like this:

```py
@app.route('/static/<path:path>')
def static(path):
    return send_from_directory('/path/to/static/files/', path)
```